# why does it show error that "x must be numeric" when I used Airquality in RStudio

Tags: r, plot

Error in hist.default(airquality$wind) : 'x' must be numeric
I put "hist(airquality$wind)" then it shows the error. It supposes to display a histogram in the plot as I just followed the tutorial.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

If wind is incorrectly set as a non-numeric (i.e. contains values like "1" instead of 1), the following should work:

```
hist(as.numeric(airquality$wind))
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in dataset `airquality` is not a data.frame, it is a matrix. You cannot use `$` to extract columns of a matrix. Instead, you need to use `[,]` indexing. Try

```
hist(airquality[,"Wind"])
```